# Resolving "there is unknown charset/collation names" warnings on views

Tags: mariadb, view, collation, character-set, mariadb-10.3

I recently moved our MySQL 5.6 server over to MariaDB 10.3.10 and, for the most part, have not had any problems. We have a couple of databases that have close to 1000 views which are now filling the log file with warnings which read:

```
View 'dm'.'v_conservation_20110906': there is unknown charset/collation names (client: ''; connection: '').
View 'dm'.'v_conservation_20110913': there is unknown charset/collation names (client: ''; connection: '').
View 'dm'.'v_conservation_20110920': there is unknown charset/collation names (client: ''; connection: '').
View 'dm'.'v_conservation_20110927': there is unknown charset/collation names (client: ''; connection: '').
```

I probably wouldn't be too concerned about it but each time the database is hit the log file grows by over 1200 lines. And that is from just one database.

When I made the switch both mysql_update and mysqlcheck with auto repair were run with no errors related to the views in question. I also removed everything from the ini file for the new installation except those things that were required. The ini file contents are:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
port=3306
datadir = "D:/SQL_Data"
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation_server='utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
max_allowed_packet = 128M
```

A lot of searching here and via Google has not provided any concrete suggestions of things to try. I would be grateful for a hint on where to look to even find out what the unknown charset/collation names are. Even better would be a way to fix the hundreds of views that apparently need fixing.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE VIEW dm.v_conservation_20110906;`  (or any one).  Preferably run it on both servers; I suspect there will be a difference.  Then tell us how the `VIEWs` were `CREATEd` on the new server.

Comment: The old server is no more so only the result from the MariaDB instance is available. `v_conservation_20110906 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`xxxxx`@`%` SQL... utf8 utf8_general_ci 
` ... definer name changed to protect the guilty.

Comment: Is WordPress involved?  If so, what version?  See https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/02/the-utf8mb4-upgrade/

Comment: No WordPress in sight sir.